# How do I find the sum of the infinite geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$2/3-2/9+2/27-2/81+\cdots$$
The formula is $$\mathrm{sum}= \frac{A_g}{1-r}\,.$$
To find the ratio, I did the following:
$$r=\frac29\Big/\frac23$$
Then got:
$$\frac29 \cdot \frac32= \frac13=r$$
and $$A_g= \frac23$$
Then I plug it all in and get:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{sum} &= \frac23 \Big/ \left(1-\frac13\right)\\
             &= \frac23 \Big/ \left(\frac33-\frac13\right)\\
             &= \frac23 \Big/ \frac23\\
             &= \frac23 \cdot \frac32\\
             &= 1\,.
\end{align*}$$

But the real answer is $\frac12$.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: The common ratio $r$ is $-1/3$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks

Comment: Thanks guys, now i understand that I forgot to add the negative sign in the beginning of solving the eqn. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Minor slip.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the terms are alternating in sign. $\displaystyle r = \frac{\frac{2}{9}}{-\frac{2}{3}} = -\frac{1}{3}$.

Note the minus sign.

Hence the sum is $\displaystyle \frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1 - (-\frac{1}{3})} = \frac{\frac{2}{3}}{\frac{4}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: you meant the reciprocal

Comment: @Anurag. 3am here. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Your common ratio should be 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{-2/9}{2/3}=\frac{-1}{3}.$$

(You missed the sign of the successive term).

Now compute your answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac23 - \frac29 + \frac2{27} - \frac2{81} + \dots
= 
\frac23\left(1 + (-\frac13) + (-\frac13)^2 + (-\frac13)^3 + ...\right)
$$

Now just use the formula:
$$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots = \frac1{1-x}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{9}+\frac{2}{27}-\frac{2}{81}+...$$

$$\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{27}+\cdots - (\frac{2}{9}+\frac{2}{81}+\cdots)$$

$$2(\dfrac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{9}}) - 2(\dfrac{\frac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{1}{9}})$$

$$2.(\frac{3}{8}) - 2(\frac{1}{8})$$
$$\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

If we are willing to be a little too casual (OK, much too casual), let the sum be $S$. Then

$$S=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{9}+\frac{2}{27}-\frac{2}{81}+\cdots.\tag{1}$$
Multiply through by $3$. We get 
$$3S=2-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{9}-\frac{2}{27}+\cdots.\tag{2}$$
Add, and note the almost total cancellation. We get
$$4S=2.$$

**Remark:** Note that for the series $1-3+9-27+\cdots$ the procedure yields the nonsensical (?) sum $\frac{3}{4}$. But the procedure yields the correct answer whenever the original series converges.

Comment: Keep in mind that this **only works if the series converges absolutely**--equivalently, if the series constructed from the absolute value of each term converges (as this series does, for if you take the absolute value of each term, you get a geometric series with $r=1/3$, which converges, therefore the original series also converges). If the series converges only **[conditionally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence)**, or diverges, this process is mathematically unsound due to the Riemann series theorem (and using it can get you strange results like $1+2+3+4+\cdots=-1/12$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=2/3-2/9+2/27-2/81+\cdots$

Let this be equation 1

Multiply, both sides by $\large\frac{-1}{3}$

$\large \frac{-S}{3}=-2/9+2/27-2/81+\cdots$

Let this be equation 2

Subtract 2 from 1

$\large {S+\frac{S}{3}=\frac {2}{3}}$

$\large  \frac {4S}{3}=\large \frac{2}{3}$

Or, $S=\large \frac{1}{2}$